# Template of a using template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a using :

```
template<typename T>
using Parser = T(* const)(std::string const &);
```

So how can i use this template in a function template ?

I want to be able to use it like this :

```
char Digit(std::string const &str)
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
    char r;
    Try<Digit>(r, "0");
}
```

But i'm struggling to declare this function template :

```
template <???>
bool Try(T &result, std::string const &str)
{
    static_assert(p != nullptr, "Parser cannot be null.");

    try {
        result = p(str);
        return true;
    } catch (std::exception const &e) { // Just for the example
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure there is a way to do it, as this worked :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
using Parser = T(*)(std::string const &);

template <Parser<char> p>
bool Try(char &result, std::string const &str)
{
    static_assert(p != nullptr, "Parser cannot be null.");

    try {
        result = p(str);
        return true;
    } catch (std::exception const &e) {
        return false;
    }
}

char Digit(std::string const &str)
{
    char const c = str[0];

    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        return c;

    throw std::exception(); // Just for the example
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc <= 1)
        return 1;

    char r;
    std::cout << Try<Digit>(r, argv[1]) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to declare the template in every way i could think of:

```
template <template<typename> Parser p, typename T>
bool Try(T &result, std::string const &str);

template <Parser<typename> p, typename T>
bool Try(T &result, std::string const &str);

template <Parser<typename> typename p, typename T>
bool Try(T &result, std::string const &str);

template <Parser p, typename T>
bool Try(T &result, std::string const &str);

template <Parser<typename T> p>
bool Try(T &result, std::string const &str);
```

But none of that seems to work.

Comment: Your 4th option works, although you have to write `Try<Digit, char>(r, argv[1])`.  Are you trying to get it to deduce the second type?

Comment: 4th didn't worked for me, and yes.
@bolov found the answer, thank you for helping !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me you want to have a function as a template argument. If so then you can do this:

If you want to use parser then you do it like this:

```
template <Parser<char> F>
bool Try(char &result, std::string const &str)
{
    try {
        result = F(str);
        return true;
    } catch (std::exception const &e) {
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char r;
    Try<Digit>(r, "0");
}
```

Btw `Parser<char>` is `char (* const)(std::string const &)` so you could use that instead.

Or if you want to make it more generic:

```
template <auto F, class T>
bool Try(T &result, std::string const &str)
{
    try {
        result = F(str);
        return true;
    } catch (std::exception const &e) {
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char r;
    Try<Digit>(r, "0");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I guess the ``auto`` here replaces a lack of syntax ?

Comment: @heheheha not necessarily. It's just that I had a hard time reading your post and understanding what you want to achieve and `auto` is the more easy and succsing way. I've updated the post to show an example using your `Parser`.

Comment: Possibly more constrained `std::invoke_result_t<F, const std::string &>& result`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how one normally does it. Passing the callable into the template parameter doesn't let you pass e.g. capturing lambdas. Usually you'd pass it as a function argument of a templated type, and use `std::invoke`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>

char Digit(const std::string &str)
{
    (void)str;
    return 'a';
}

template <typename Parser>
bool Try(
    Parser &&parser,
    std::invoke_result_t<Parser, const std::string &> &result,
    const std::string &str
)
{
    try
    {
        result = std::invoke(std::forward<Parser>(parser), str);
        return true;
    }
    catch (std::exception &)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char r;
    Try(Digit, r, "0");
}
```